# Private gitlab registry: How can the latest version of a module be installed?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Published modules in gitlab private registry not updating to latest version when run `npm install` in another app.

Running `npm outdated` shows the latest version as `wanted` as below but it's not installing it on `npm install`.

```
Package                                     Current | Wanted | Latest                                                 Depended by
@username/package_name                      0.1.9   | 0.1.10 | 0.1.10
```

I tried with removing `node_modules` as well as `npm install -f` but non of seems to work.

Is there anyway to get the latest available module when do a `npm install`.

Comment: You might be able to run `npm update` in there? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-update

Comment: @fravolt Thanks. running `npm update` solved the problem. but I have a small concern about other packages. Since `npm update` updates the all other packages to latest version as well, So there could issues for longer run. What's your idea on this. Is it safe or not ?

Comment: That's always a risk of course. If you're certain you can safely update certain packages you can always specify the package names in your `npm update` command

Comment: Yes, But there are around +40 packages I'm planning to get from gitlab so it's not efficient to run `npm update` with package name. 

Does `npm private packages` also behave like this ? or they work fine ? if so i can move to `npm`